# C# FFmpeg bitmap frames to picturebox

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I have an existing C# winforms app with live videostreams from 4 ip cameras via VLC.net (rtsp) and we take every 100ms a snapshot to analize. This is working fine. Now we like to do this instead of VLC.net with FFmpeg to have more possibilities with the (faster) captured frame. I have already a working ffmpeg wrapper sending every frame as bitmap via an event. Then I have a class "FmpegVideoWindow" inherits from PictureBox, here we listen for incoming frames and draw them on the picturebox. So instead of using the vlc-control in the form we use now a picturebox  :

```
 private void ffMpegWrapper_NewFrame1(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e != null)
        {                

            try
            {                   

                using (Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(e.Frame))
                {
                    frame = (Bitmap)bm.Clone();                                              

                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }               

        }

        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
        if (frame != null)
        {
            pe.Graphics.DrawImage(frame, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
           //todo : disposing frame
        }

    }
```

This is working ok to see the cameras live, they have @25fps and a D1 resolution 704*576.
The problem is that every time we have other processing like opening a (settings)form, or analyzing the snapshot, the picture in the picturebox is freezing for a short time. The same program with VLC.net was never a problem.

The Ffmpeg process is done in another thread. Why does the VLC.net control running smooth in the GUI thread, and this new approach not? And what can we do to fix it? The analyzing is also done in another thread, writing the results from the analyzer to the database is done in the GUI thread. And I don't like to change that because with VLC.net it was also not needed to do that.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you pinpointed the cause? I mean: does your render loop stall? If so, is it the `ffMpegWrapper_NewFrame1` or the actual drawing? Or is `ffMpegWrapper_NewFrame1` giving you the same frame?

Comment: Hi Stefan, as far as I see now there occurs a delay around 20ms while drawing.

Comment: Isn't that a half of a frame? Is that while performing the `OnPaint`?

Comment: yes, sometimes longer, but it is annoying to have it. It is in onpaint.